# Cannot import installed package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror

I was following the [Packaging Python projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial and everything was working fine. I uploaded my package to pypi and I can install it.
However upon importing, something odd happens;
Inside the shell, it works fine.

```py
>>> import noodle_extensions
>>> # no errors indicate that it was imported properly.
>>> print(noodle_extensions)
<module 'noodle_extensions' from 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\noodle_extensions\\__init__.py'>
```

However, inside VScode, I get this;

```py
import noodle_extensions
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/OneDrive/Desktop/Codes/Python/Tests/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import noodle_extensions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'noodle_extensions'
```

control+clicking it does not work. pylint thinks that it doesn't exist. 
In terms of files at the `pip install` location, I have the `noodle_extensions` containing the `__init__.py`, the `.egg-info` folder and a `.dist-info` folder.
Is there something I can do?
[PyPi site](https://pypi.org/project/NoodleExtensions/)

Comment: Are you sure that vscode and the terminal are using the same Python version and environment?

Comment: Good point, forgot to check that. How would I check? I think they're both on 3.9 but since I have two versions installed it's possible that one of them is still on 3.8

EDIT: Bottom left corner of VS-code. VScode is still on 3.8. Thank you!

Comment: Multiple Python versions is almost always what this is.

Comment: _"How would I check?"_ - You could for example `print(sys.executable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, the module "`noodle_extensions`" exists in the environment "`Python3.9`", please click on the Python interpreter displayed in the lower left corner of VSCode (or use `F1`, `python: Select Interpreter`), and then select "`Python3.9`":

[image]

Or reinstall the module "`noodle_extensions`" in the currently selected "`Python3.8`" environment.

Check the installation package:

[image]

Reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mismatch between your PYTHONPATH on the terminal and the VSCode. Make sure you select the right python interpreter in VSCode (bottom left).

To check your interpreter when you run from terminal use the command:

```sh
# Linux:
$ which python
# Windows:
> where python 
# or 
> where py
```

In case you are using a python virtual environment, make sure your package is installed/available in the environment and the environment is configured VSCode `launch.json`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my VSCODE setup. My solution may sound extremely dumb, but all I had to do was close and restart VSCODE and the import started showing.